# SetInterval is Not Working with If condition

Tags: javascript, setinterval

> This condition `setIntervalIdMessages == 0` make `setInterval` not work
>   i dont know why
>
> This Is the all condition  that make setInterval not to work

```
if (NewMessageCounter > 0 && setIntervalIdMessages == 0)
```

> This Is working   `if (NewMessageCounter > 0 )`
>
> I see in crhome debug that the value of  setIntervalIdMessages  is 0
>   and is see that the line of setInterval code is exeuting

```
var setIntervalIdMessages  = 0; 

   $.ajax({
            url: '/P/GetC',
            type: "POST",           
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (counters) {

                var NewMessageCounter = parseInt(counters.NewMessageCounter, 10);
                var NewWatchedMeCounter = parseInt(counters.NewWatchedMeCounter, 10);


                var glower = $('.glowDiv');

                if (NewMessageCounter > 0 && setIntervalIdMessages == 0) {

                    $('#UserMessagesDiv').addClass('glowDiv');

                    setIntervalIdMessages = window.setInterval(function () {
                        glower.toggleClass('active');
                    }, 500);

                }


        });
```

Comment: Is `glower` defined at that point? I see you only do `addClass('glowDiv')` after trying to get it earlier. Do a `console.log(glower)` inside the setinterval function to see if it has a value.

Comment: Problem most probably is in your these lines... `var NewMessageCounter = parseInt(counters.NewMessageCounter, 10);` or `var NewWatchedMeCounter = parseInt(counters.NewWatchedMeCounter, 10);`. You should better check what are values of variables `NewMessageCounter` and `NewWatchedMeCounter`.

Answer (score 0):

i think `your code should work fine`,may be check your `if condition if it is satisfying or not`.

**small demo:**

```js
  var NewMessageCounter= 4;
 var setIntervalIdMessages  = 0; 
var glower = $('.glowDiv');
if(NewMessageCounter > 0 && setIntervalIdMessages == 0){//your condition comes here
  setIntervalIdMessages = window.setInterval(function () {
         glower.toggleClass('active');
     }, 500);

}
```

```css
.active{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="glowDiv">
     text here
</div>
```